# MongoDB find where $value exists and timestamp $gte JS

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm trying to search for the existence of a nested element, as well as getting a timestamp greater than:

```
 db.stats.find(  { $and:  [ { 'data.Statistics': {$exists: true} },{ timestamp: {$gte: 1} } ] }
```

From the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/#) I can't see where I'm going wrong, but I'm not getting anything back.

Just doing:

```
var query = {};     
query["data.Statistics"] = {$exists: true}
```

works however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **[`$and`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/)** operator is not really necessary in this case as it can be implicitly used by just specifying a comma separated list of expressions thus you can re-write your query as:

```
db.stats.find({ 
    "data.Statistics": { "$exists": true },
    "timestamp": { "$gte": 1 } 
});
```

If using a variable to create the query object using the square-bracket notation, you can approach it like

```
var query = {};     
query["data.Statistics"] = { "$exists": true };
query["timestamp"] = { "$gte": 1 };

db.stats.find(query);
```